# SQL union grouped by rows

Tags: sql, database, group-by, union, union-all

Assume I have a table like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| commonrow | one | two | null |
| commonrow | null | null | three |

How to produce a result to look like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| commonrow | one | two | three |

Thanks

Comment: many thanks to @eshirvana and for edits to marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this, you can group by col1 and get the maximum in each group:

```
select col1 , max(col2) col2 , max(col3) col3 , max(col4) col4
from table 
group by col1
```